What is the right connector for .parquet files?
We have a monthly ETL that imports a new folder with 1 .parquet file inside an Azure Blob Storage each month.

I tried to use parquet connector to connect and merge those files:

But when I give the URL
https://mystuff.blob.core.windows.net/aws-billing-and-cost-management/Export_Billing_Overwrite/Export_Billing_Overwrite/data/
to the Parquet connector I receive a 404:

This because Power BI can only connect to 1 .parquet file, something like:
https://mystuff.blob.core.windows.net/aws-billing-and-cost-management/Export_Billing_Overwrite/Export_Billing_Overwrite/data/BILLING_PERIOD=2022-01/Export_Billing_Overwrite-00001.snappy.parquet

But I don't want to take only 1 of them. I want to merge them all.
I then tried using the Azure Blob Storage connector:

This time all the files are merged:

Is Power BI clever enough to read those .parquet files as Parquet (so we read fast) or is Power BI reading those files as CSV files (so we go slow)?
